# Show/hide spinner depending if file is null React Js

Tags: reactjs

When pressing button I want to show a spinner when file is equal to null. Then when file is finally uploaded and is not null anymore, hide spinnder and run a function. Heres my code. Thanks.

```
const submitAndPhoto = (e) => {
    try {
      if (imageUrls == null) {
        setShow(true);
        setTimeout(submitAndPhoto, 200);
      } else {
        setShow(false);

        uploadFile();
        submit();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you using hooks? Does `uploadFile` returning response when file finish uploading?

Comment: Hi. Well, nop. Can you give me an example, please? I would appreciate it.